# Meta requires OpenID?

Tags: support, meta

How do I ask a question on metastackoverflow without an openid?

It says, "you must type your name or openid" and where do I type a nickname if I have no openid?

On Stack Overflow, at least, it asks for "openid or name email homepage", but here I see only an openid textbox.

Comment: Belons on meta . . . sorry, I couldn't resist :)

Comment: See my [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56762/unregistered-user-description-incorrect-on-meta) related to this as well... it's really really similar, but not _quite_ a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Comment: Are those... *invisible emoticons*?

Comment: They're advanced space fillers.

Comment: That's what Jeff said, but your post generates a lot more XML tags, which requires more CPU cycles, and thus takes longer to display and consumes more power.  You're too frippery.  `<em><code> </code></em> You can't. <em><code> </code></em>`

Comment: Welbog, stop stealing our CPU cycles, you magnificent bastard!

Answer (score 4):

**Meta requires OpenID?**

Yes.

**How do I ask a question on metastackoverflow without an openid?**

- Use a throw away openid account - they are trivially easy to get from lots of providers. (best solution)
- Ask on SO and have the question migrated (frowned upon).
- Get one of the tens of thousands of SO users to install a keylogger, and use their openid (possibly illegal).

Answer (score 3):

Meta requires an openid; anonymous posting is disabled here.

Comment: That's what I said, but you used a lot more letters. You're too verbose, Jeff.

Comment: The funny thing is that he actually managed it to ask an anonymous question here ;) So the correct answer is: ask on SO and get migrated.

Comment: lol, you're right! I hadn't considered that "loophole"...

Answer (score 0):

If Meta requires OpenID, then **FIX YOUR STUFF!**

1) Attempting to ask or answer a question here without being logged in produces the following error message:

"•name and email, or your OpenID, are missing"

That implies that a name and email address would be sufficient.

2) Click around enough (the "register" and "log in" links are confusing and the whole thing needs re-thinking, so I can't remember for certain, but I think it was on the "forgot your account information" page, which I can't find again at this moment), and you'll be informed, and I quote (yes, I copied the text when I had that page open in my browser):

"...does not require an email address to participate..."

I guess that's an ambiguous exerpt, but the text on that page led me to believe I didn't need an OpenID associated with an email address.

I'm a geek too, but I prefer NOT to use OpenID, and the hassle of using SO without one is so great, that I try to avoid SO for the most part, which is a bummer, because everything else you've done is **AWESOME**

Comment: so use Facebook login, that's OAuth 2.0 instead. Congrats, you're not using OpenID! :)

Comment: Let's not get started on Facebook.  ;-)  Point is, SO Meta's own error text and other information give the exact opposite information - that OpenID is NOT required to use Meta.  It'd be a lot more clear if this were in the FAQ or on the front page - I had to read a few posts all the way through before I could figure it out, and I have more PATIENCE.